# How do I skip a specific panel using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

I want to hide a specific panel. For example, when I select “Next”, panel 2 skips. Resulting in only seeing Panel 1, Panel 3, Panel 4. Is there a code I can use that makes a panel inactive?  One method I tried was removing the active class. *$(:nth-child(2)).removeClass('active');* The result did not work. Does anyone else know how I can skip panel 2? Below I attached the code to the effect. If voted down, please explain why, that way I can improve when utilizing the discussion board. Thank you.

```js
var $fieldsets =
    $('#panels .sets')
    .first()
    .addClass('active')

    .end()
    .not(':first')
    .hide()
    .end();
$(':nth-child(3)').removeClass("active").css('display', 'none');


//doesnt affect 


var $panelControlButtons =
    $('#panelcontrol button')
    .filter('.btnPrev')
    .prop('disabled', true)
    .end();


$('#panelcontrol')
    .on('click', 'button', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        switch (true) {
            case $(this).hasClass('btnNext'):
                var $newFieldset =
                    $fieldsets
                    .filter('.active')
                    .hide()
                    .removeClass('active')
                    .next()
                    .addClass('active')
                    .show();


                //enable Prev button
                $panelControlButtons
                    .filter('.btnPrev')
                    .prop('disabled', false);

                //disabled Next button
                if ($newFieldset.is(':last-child')) {
                    $panelControlButtons
                        .filter('.btnNext')
                        .prop('disabled', true);
                }




                break; // btnNext
                var $input =
                    $('input')
                    .filter('.active')
                    .end();
            case $(this).hasClass('btnPrev'):
                var $newFieldset =
                    $fieldsets
                    .filter('.active') //selects the current fieldset
                    .hide() //hide it 
                    .removeClass('active') //remove active flag
                    .prev() //move to the previous fieldset
                    .addClass('active') //flag as active
                    .show(); //and show it

                // enable Next button
                $panelControlButtons
                    .filter('.btnNext')
                    .prop('disabled', false);

                // disable Prev button   
                if ($newFieldset.is(':first-child')) {
                    $panelControlButtons
                        .filter('.btnPrev')
                        .prop('disabled', true);
                }
                break; // btn Prev

        }

    }); // panelcontrol button handler
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="engl">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:700" rel="stylesheet"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="simplegrid.css">
<script src="jquery/main.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">

</head>

<body>




<div id="container">
 <div id="panels">
     <div class="sets"> <h1>PANEL 1</h1>
   <div><input type="text" name="ss1" value=""/></div>
       <div class="asciiCode"></div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="sets two"> <h1>PANEL 2</h1>
   <div><input name="ss2" value=""/></div>
       <div class="asciiCode"></div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="sets"> <h1>PANEL 3</h1>
   <div><input name="ss3" value=""/></div>
       <div class="asciiCode"></div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="sets"> <h1>PANEL 4</h1>
   <div><input name="ss4" value=""/></div>
       <div class="asciiCode"></div>
        </div>
    </div>



</div>


 <div id="panelcontrol">
       <button class="btnPrev">Prev</button>
        <button class="btnNext">Next</button>
      </div>




      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>


 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off to add classes instead of removing them.

Find the css to do the hiding, put it in a class, then in your jQuery where you tried removing, add instead.